# C# call method on a member class

Tags: c#

I want do something like that:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String varA{ get; set; }
    public String[] varB{ get; set; }

    //.....
    public ?? string ToHtml()
    {
        //return HTML value
    }
}

public class Run()
{
    MyClass c = new Myclass();
    c.varA = "Toto";
    c.varB = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };

    string a = c.varA.ToHtml() // -> "<p>Toto</p>";
    string b = c.varB.ToHtml() // -> "<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul>";
}
```

How can do that ?

Edit: I have change the Run()

Comment: What does `ToHtml` do? What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can't call it on the `varA` and `varB` fields because they are not instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: Can you try to explain why you wish to do this?

Comment: @Will Vousden I think OP asking how to do that :)

Comment: and varB is a string array while varA is a string, they are not the same kind of objects what do you want to do exactly? an extension method on string class maybe!?

Comment: @astander I have Edit the Run() for explain why y want do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to implement your scenario with extension methods. While, as others have noted, it would make sense to keep the logic to turn your strings to HTML within MyClass, in certain scenarios it might make sense to use this approach.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String varA{ get; set; }
    public String[] varB{ get; set; }           
}

public static class MyExtensions {
    public static string ToHtml(this string input, string format)
    {
        return string.Format(format, input);
    }

    public static string ToHtml(this string input)
    {
        return ToHtml(input,"<p>{0}</p>");
    }

    public static string ToHtml(this IEnumerable<string> input, string wrapperformat, string elementformat)
    {
        string body= input
                        .Select(s => string.Format(elementformat,s))
                        .Aggregate((a,b)=> a+b);
        return string.Format(wrapperformat,body);
    }

    public static string ToHtml(this IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        return ToHtml(input,"<ul>{0}</ul>","<li>{0}</li>");         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an extension method on the String class, which returns a HTML representation of that string (or whatever ToHtml() should do).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static string ToHtml ( this string target )
   {
       // TODO : 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you define `ToHtml()` extension methods for both strings and arrays, you can't call it that way (on the fields themselves). See the other answers for how to implement extension methods.

A simpler alternative that applies to just `MyClass` is to make two overloads of your method which accept a string and a string array as arguments respectively, then pass them:

```
public string ToHtml(string arg)
{
    //return HTML value
}

public string ToHtml(string[] argAsArray)
{
    //return HTML value
}
```

Then call them like this:

```
string a = c.ToHtml(c.varA);
string b = c.ToHtml(c.varB);
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want but I am going to use this solution.
I think I can not do that I want..

Comment: @scrat789: You can use extension methods, have you seen the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is add an helper method to the `string` class. It's called an extension method and it must respect certains rules :

- It must use `this` on the first parameter
- It must be static
- It must be in a static class

.

```
public static class HtmlStringHelper
{
  public static string ToHtml(this string s)
  {
    // Add you logic here
    return (s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suppose you *could* use an extension method (for both string and string[] for that), but then you would not need the ToHtml() method of MyClass (as the logic would reside in the extension methods).

edit: i should note that calling member methods usually is considered a bad practice. Without more information its hard to imagine what MyClass is supposed to do/be, but you might want to keep control of class members in the class. So another way would be to create a ToHtmlA() and ToHtmlB() method for MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed `ToHtml` to except a value:

```
public static string ToHtml(string a)
{
    // your code here - obviously not returning ""
    return "";
}
```

then you can call it like so:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.varA = "some text";
c.varA = MyClass.ToHtml(c.varA);
```

But, I maybe WAY off what you require.